# Alternating current changing direction

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current

As we all know AC is is supplied to our homes. As Ac switches direction constantly why only   the live wire is hot and there is no negative cycle in nuetra

Comment: In the US the neutral conductor is bonded to ground at the service panel. Where do you live?

Answer (score 0):

Electric current flows in circles: that's why we call electrical networks "circuits". Assuming your electricity is correctly connected according to code, the current on the neutral has the same magnitude and the opposite direction of the current on the hot, thus completing the circle.

Potential (voltage) is different: the neutral is bonded to ground (literal Earth ground in this case). So, its potential relative to ground is small. The hot wire is not bonded to ground, allowing the potential difference that, together with the current, delivers power to lights and appliances.